# Problem with javascript and user-input on website to make a darkmode switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see, I have a javascript which is supposed to make a darkmode switch on a website. javascript works I get the alert but nothing happens when I press the switch. Why?
Note: I am very new to programming and stuff, so explanations for an idiot would be great.
----example.html----

```
  <a href="#" class="right">
    <button type="button" onclick="func()">Darkmode</button>
  </a>
```

---script.js---

```
let darkmode = 0
function func() {
    if(darkmode = 0){
        document.getElementById("main").style.background = "grey";
        document.getElementById("row").style.background = "grey";
        document.getElementById("footer").style.background = "grey";
        darkmode = 1;}
    else{
        document.getElementById("main").style.background = "white";
        document.getElementById("row").style.background = "white";
        document.getElementById("footer").style.background = "white";
        darkmode = 0;}
  }
alert("11 hot singles in your area");
```

----style.css---- (f.e. the main stuff from css)

```
  /* Main column */
  .main {   
    -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 70%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: your `if` statement uses a single `=`. Meaning you're assigning instead of comparing a value. You need atleast two `==` to [compare values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Also note a simpler approach will be to toggle a class on the body and add css rules like `.darkmode .main,  .darkmode footer, .darkmode .row{background-color:grey}`

Comment: And finally your css for `.main` is a class selector. `getElementById()` is for id not classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your js that when you compare you should put `==` instead of `=`. SO your js will be:

```js
let darkmode = 0
function func() {
    if(darkmode == 0){
        document.getElementById("main").style.background = "grey";
        document.getElementById("row").style.background = "grey";
        document.getElementById("footer").style.background = "grey";
        darkmode = 1;}
    else{
        document.getElementById("main").style.background = "white";
        document.getElementById("row").style.background = "white";
        document.getElementById("footer").style.background = "white";
        darkmode = 0;}
  }
alert("11 hot singles in your area");
```

Comment: There is a close reason for typos. Answering typo issues provides no long term value to the knowledge base

Answer (score 0):

You got a very funny bug there

instead of
`if (darkmode = 0)`

it should be
`if (darkmode === 0)`

and that is just it

Comment: There is a close reason for typos. Answering typo issues provides no long term value to the knowledge base or future readers